# Pandas Series constructor produces NaN values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, nan, series

Pandas Series constructor produces NaN values when passed a dictionary where the key is a tuple with one of the elements as a datetime.  The code is below.

Strangely, it's not happening when the key is a single datetime, or a tuple without datetimes.

It seems this behavior was introduced in pandas 0.15.0, since it works fine in 0.14.1, however I can't find anything in the release notes.

I'm running 64-bit Python 2.7 on Windows.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

d = {
    (datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), 'k1'): 1,
    (datetime.date(2016, 5, 2), 'k2'): 2
}

print 'Dictionary:'
print d
print

s = pd.Series(d)
print 'Series:'
print s
print

df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys()))
print 'DataFrame:'
print df
print
```

Output:

```
Dictionary:
{(datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), 'k1'): 1, (datetime.date(2016, 5, 2), 'k2'): 2}

Series:
2016-05-01  k1   NaN
2016-05-02  k2   NaN
dtype: float64

DataFrame:
               0
2016-05-01 k1  1
2016-05-02 k2  2
```

Comment: Yeah, this is weird.  I get the same behavior as you when using `datetime.date`, but it works as written if I use `datetime.datetime` instead.  If you look at the index in the `NaN` output, pandas has added a time component to each date.  Perhaps there's a bug where it does that conversion?

Comment: iirc this was fixed in 0.18.0 (might be in 0.17.1 as well)

Comment: @Jeff I'm using 0.18.1 and am seeing the same behavior.

Comment: well ``datetime.date`` is not a first class type, so wouldn't fix anyhow. no reason ever to use it. you can put a request on the issue tracker and fix with a pull-request if you'd like.

Comment: @root is correct, every version from 0.15.0 to 0.18.1 included shows this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

That is bizarre!  Has to be a bug.

Here are some of my experiments:

What you did:

```
s = pd.Series({(datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), 'k1'): 1,
               (datetime.date(2016, 5, 2), 'k2'): 2})

s

2016-05-01  k1    NaN
2016-05-02  k2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Experiment #1: use `strftime` Returns a string, not what you want.  But works.

```
s = pd.Series({(datetime.date(2016, 5, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'k1'): 1,
               (datetime.date(2016, 5, 2).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'k2'): 2})

s

2016-05-01  k1    1
2016-05-02  k2    2
dtype: int64
```

Experiment #2: use `pd.to_datetime`.  This works

```
s = pd.Series({(pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2016, 5, 1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'k1'): 1,
               (pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2016, 5, 2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'k2'): 2})

s

2016-05-01  k1    1
2016-05-02  k2    2
dtype: int64
```

Experiment #3: use `pd.Timestamp`.  This also works

```
s = pd.Series({(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2016, 5, 1)), 'k1'): 1,
               (pd. Timestamp(datetime.date(2016, 5, 2)), 'k2'): 2})

s

2016-05-01  k1    1
2016-05-02  k2    2
dtype: int64
```